# How to get rid of this boiler plate code

Tags: scala

I am writing a web services project using http4s and everytime I write a new data object which is sent in or out of the web service, I need to write the following code

```
import argonaut.{Argonaut, CodecJson}
import org.http4s.{EntityDecoder, EntityEncoder}
import org.http4s.argonaut._

final case class Name (name: String, age : Int)
object Name {
    implicit val codec : CodecJson[Name] = 
        Argonaut.casecodec2(Name.apply, Name.unapply)("name", "age")
    implicit val decoder : EntityDecoder[Name] = jsonOf[Name]
    implicit val encoder : EntityEncoder[Name] = jsonEncoderOf[Name]
}
```

Based on the number of fields in the case class, I needed to use corresponding casecodeX method (where x is the number of fields) and then pass it a list of fields.

Can you please tell me what is the best way so that I don't have to write the code which is currently in the companion object.

An idea which I have is that I should write a macro which parses the code of the Name class and then spits out the class containing the codec, encoder, decoder. But I have no idea how to go forward with the implementation of this macro.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

For the codec, you can use [argonaut-shapeless](https://github.com/alexarchambault/argonaut-shapeless), specifically [JsonCodec](https://github.com/alexarchambault/argonaut-shapeless#jsoncodec-for-local-argonautshapeless_-import). For the encoder/decoder, you can pass `jsonOf` as `decoder` to the functions you're calling, and implicit derivation should do the rest for you. Sadly you can't get around `jsonOf`, [it has been tried](https://github.com/http4s/http4s/pull/690).

Also read: http://http4s.org/docs/0.15/json.html

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if it would be really better or not, but you could start with generic implicits for encoder and decoder:

```
implicit def decoder[A](implicit cj: CodecJson[A]): EntityDecoder[A] = jsonOf[A]
implicit val encoder[A](implicit cj: CodecJson[A]) : EntityEncoder[A] = jsonEncoderOf[A]
```

On that step you are getting read of 2/3 of boilerplate.
The other part is trickier: you could go with macro or reflection.
I know nothing about macro, but with reflection the reduction wouldn't be as significant to make you want to use it:

```
def generateCodecJson[A](implicit ClassTag[A]): CodecJson[A] = …
```

and you still have to provide the companion object and call that function to generate CodecJson. Not really sure if it worth effort.

Comment: this is a good suggestion. the encode/decode can easily be taken care of. but we still need to figure out a good solution for codec. I wish there was some good resource to show how to write a macro which generates scala code.

Comment: You can derive json instances, take a look at argonaut-shapeless.

Comment: @Stremlenye I wouldn't recommend the decoder/encoder. It will come back to bite you. https://github.com/http4s/http4s/pull/690

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with Scala. But I think this situation you faced is similar in Java. In Java, all those code are imported by IDE when you inputed a token which is unknown in current namespace. You can just try and use a better IDE, such as Intellij IDEA.

Comment: I don't like this suggestion.

Comment: 1) It is not boilerplate brought in by the IDE. 2) This is not an Eclipse vs IDEA issue. 3) The boilerplate is required in Scala to reduce the coding effort for transforming data structures. 4) The OP's boilerplate code is more verbose than it should be.